# ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException while XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:953)

Tags: google-app-engine, exception, smack

I'm getting following error:

> exception(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:953))
>   while connecting through my Android app deployed on google app engine.

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1568)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:253)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:64)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:196)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:193)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:193)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:64)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:107)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.apiProxyMakeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:58)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.NameServiceImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(NameServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.google.apphosting.util.ResolverManager$AppEngineNameservice.lookupAllHostAddr(ResolverManager.java:42)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1388)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1341)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1255)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1186)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1136)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:220)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.proxy.DirectSocketFactory.createSocket(DirectSocketFactory.java:28)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:512)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:953)
    at ee.ut.notification.xmpp.server.SessionHandler.login(SessionHandler.java:28)
    at ee.ut.notification.xmpp.server.SessionHandler.<init>(SessionHandler.java:21)
    at ee.ut.notification.xmpp.server.MessagingFramework.initialize(MessagingFramework.java:33)
    at ee.ut.notification.xmpp.server.MessagingFramework.<init>(MessagingFramework.java:18)
```

Answer (score 2):

> The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.

Isn't that error message verbose enough?

Comment: haha, still a good question and answer since App Engine was not showing any stack trace and/or enable billing message